# When did Lord Shiva slash Lord Vishnu's head off.?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

In **Lord Shiva's thousand names** according to **Shiva Maha Purana** there is a name which is number **(755)** **Vishnukandharapatana** which translates to **"the one who slashes Vishnu's head."**

Here in [Shiva Purana, Kotirudra Samhita, Chapter 35 Pg 1410 second line you’ll find Vishnukandharapatan](https://archive.org/details/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart3/page/n347/mode/2up).

So my question is **when did that happen.?**

Comment: This seems to be from the fight b/w Shiva's incarnation Sharbha and Vishnu's incarnation Narsimha..

Comment: But for that another name is there Narsimha nipatanaha so I think if it was about that than the name Narsimha would have been used instead of vishnu. But as far as I know lord vishnu was beheaded only by maa mahamaya as an ant during the incarnation of hygriva avatar. Still let's wait if anyone knows about any other incident or not, if not than I think your answer will be the logical one.

Comment: Interesting, not heard of this incident; as YDS said the fight between Narasimha and Sharabha seems relatable.

Comment: Thanks  @Archit I will do that. .

Comment: Oh thanks man I was thinking myself how to do that. .

Comment: @SauravDey Yeah in one commentary i could see "Vishnu kandhara pataatanah or of the Swarupa of Hayagriva"..so might be related to Hayagriva as well..

Comment: [This version](http://hindumythologybynarin.blogspot.com/2014/06/shri-maha-vishnu-krutha-shiva.html) also says "826. Vishnu kandhara pataatanah - one who cut Lord Vishnu head (story of hayagriva)"

Comment: @yds yeah its saying that but as I remember it was mata parvati(mahamaya) who in the form of an ant did that.

Comment: In thousand names, the God will be Brahman..so even if some act was done by other gods still indirectly it will be attributed to that God who is being praised..u can see that few incarnations / acts of Lord Vishnu also mentioned here.. similarly few of Shiva's acts/incarnations mentioned in Vishnu sahastranam...anyway let's wait for an answer..

Comment: Ya I know that much but it's too indirect anyways ya let's wait for a proper answer. Which I don't think I will get anytime soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Linga Purana Destruction of Daksha Yagna Chapter 100.

24.Then Vişnu of great splendour and intensified strength lifted up his discus , and fought with Rudra . A terrible fight ensued between them . It made hairs to stand on end . 25-30 . Thanks to his yogic power , innumerable and divine bodies with conch , discus and iron clubs in their hands were born of Vispu . They were equal to him in lustre . Lord Virabhadra killed all of them by means of his iron club and hit Vişņu on the head . Then he sportively hit him on the chest , he fell senseless on the ground . The lord got up again and lifted up his discus to kill him . He stood there gloriously with his eyes reddened with anger . Virabhadra of undistressed soul stunned his terrible discus that had the lustre of black sun and which he had kept in his hand . He did not move . He stood stunned thereby motionless like a mountain . 31. The bow of the lord was attacked with three hits and it split into three . Through contact with the tips of the bits of the bow he cut off the head of the lord Vishnu.

Answer (score 4):

As No one was giving me any answers I had to search for myself and thankfully I think I got the answer but not the verses and so I am posting it in here.:

The description of the daksha yagna story varies according to different Puranas.

The Vamana purana states that Fearing Lord Shankar's wrath, Lord Vishnu went to [Hrishikesh](https://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vamana_purana/the_destruction_of_dakshas_yagya.html) and remained aloof for quite sometime.

The Vayu Purana mentions [Yajneshwara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajna_(avatar)), the personification of yajna (lord vishnu) took the form of an antelope and jumped towards the sky. Virabhadra captured it and decapitated [him](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daksha_yajna).

[Source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp043.htm).:

This is yagneshwara Episode is
also mentioned in the Hari Vanśa(Mahabharata): and thus accounts for the formation of the constellation Mrigasíras; Yajna, with the head of a deer, being elevated to the planetary region, by Brahmá.

In the Linga Purana, Lord Vishnu is beheaded, and his head is blown by the wind into the fire.

The Kúrma Puráńa, after describing a contest in which both parties occasionally prevail, makes Brahmá interpose, and separate the combatants.

The Kásí Khanda of the Skánda Purana describes Vishńu as defeated, and at the mercy of Vírabhadra, who is prohibited by a voice from heaven from destroying his antagonist (lord vishnu).

There are also examples of lord [sharabha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharabha)
beheading lord Narsima and the [hyagriva](http://hindumythologybynarin.blogspot.com/2014/06/shri-maha-vishnu-krutha-shiva.html?m=1) avatar of lord vishnu where he gets beheaded and his head was replaced by a horse head.

Comment: Interesting answer! So the answer for the incident is Daksha Yagya. The related Harivamsa chapter which you have mentioned you can refer here: http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/bhavishyaparva/hv_3_032_mpr.html

Comment: It's so hazy I can't tell read properly. The answer I have written you can check the source one it's there in the footnotes. Plus there was another fight which hsppend between rudra and nara narayana. I have already written I don't have the verses I have taken this summary from the Vishnu Puran footnotes. Click the source link u will get it there.

Comment: Yes, I referred the Vishnu Purana source which you had linked. I pasted the Harivamsha chapter link as well in case you or someone else would want to refer that; unfortunately it is not translated, but it still can be referred for the verses.

Comment: Which vishnu puran source you are talking about.? Are you talking about your above link. It's really though to read the verses due to that format plus it's also not translated so many people who will be reading will not understand sanskrit. Yes if you can give any like kmg version or something that will be better I guess. But still that was awesome of you. .

Comment: My bad I didn't read the page completely - I was talking about the source which you had linked, which is a link to the Vishnu Purana translation on sacred-texts.com, but the chapter you have linked is a translation of the Vayu Purana version of Daksha Yagya which the translator has given as an additional chapter.

Comment: My reference was not the chapter but the footnotes because it gives a short summary of most of the versions of the daksha yagna according to different pursnas.

Comment: got it, yes the footnotes are very informative

Comment: Yes they really are. .

Comment: Well I think it's lord shiva who has given the principles of shaivism n his identity to lord brahma, lord vishnu, lord Surya, lord Indra, etc as told in shiva gita n vibhuti section of Padma puran. N lord vishnu is the foremost Shaiva. I think all bhagwans respect eachother. According to advaitam n adi Shankaracharya brahma=vishnu=mahesh=shakti=ganesh=kartik. ️☮️.

Comment: I believe that all these puranic stories were written by men in the past to glorify their favourite God (ishta devata) and are nothing but a work of the human mind. In other words, they are just fairy tales. One god chopping another god's head off clearly shows that the followers of a particular sect (like the shaivas) were clearly trying to belittle Vishnu. If you're seeking real knowledge then read the gita and definitely the upanishads. The latter speaks of the formless, attributeless Brahman (which is not a God/Ishwara, but actually spirit or consciousness) and its relationship with jiva.

Comment: Dude u can believe what u want u m not stopping u. But Puranas are written by vedvyas who also composed mahabharata which consists of gita m there are many interpolation done by Vaishnavas also to belittle shiva like the war of shiva n vishnu in Valmiki Ramayana balkhanda. N iskon to is on different level in insulting bhagwans. So let's not go there.I hve studied gita it was there in my sanskrit syllabus but for real gyan u also study shiv gita n ishwara gita which says shiva is parambramha n bhagwat gita was a repitation of it n I believe that.

Comment: Because lord shiva is nirgun, nirakar, genderless, truth n actually the atma of all jiva. I respect n worship all bhagwans as an advaitam n celebrate all pujas. But everyone has a set of their own beliefs so u keep urs n let me keep mine. N I have posted this question because due to some research I was going through sahastra naam of shiva n I came across this n at that time I didn't know when did that happen it was not to Insult any bhagwans. Let's not stretch this topic any further, as in a democracy we both can become whatever we want. That's the beauty of it  Chalo bye. Cya. Tc. .

Comment: N yes u r right bhagwatam/god is not parambramha they are sakar sagun form of parambramha who is the only truth or consciousness. So we all worship that truth only directly or indirectly. So us arguing over such thing will be foolishness. N I don't wana argue with anyone m sure u also want the same. So let's just move on. Goodbye. Hv sdz. Cya. Bye. Tc. .

Comment: Vedas, Upanishads, Puranas, itihaaasas, etc etc all are sacred to sacred to this sanatana dharma.

Comment: Om Namah Shanti. ️☮️.

Answer (score 2):

The incident is mentioned [Chapter 100](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart2/page/n45/mode/2up) in the Shaiva Linga Purana after **Dadhicha beats up Vishnu** in battle, and curses him to be destroyed by the anger of Rudra:

> In the great sacrifice of Daksa, **Lord Rudra burned Devas along with Visnu** and sages. *(2)* His Gana named Bhadra was sent by the lord Paramesthin *(3)*

> He (Veerabhadra/Rudra) cut off the head of lord Indra ... ... Without any difficulty he killed thirty three Devas thus. Sportingly he killed three thousand three hundred and thirty three Devas along with the three leading Devas. He killed the leading sages too. This lord killed those Devas who stood in readiness for fighting. Lord Rudra hit them with his fist, swords, arrows and other things. Then Visnu of great splendour and intensified strength lifted up his discus, **and fought with Rudra** ... ... Through contact with the tips of the bits of the bow **he (Rudra) cut off the head of the lord (Vishnu).** His head that was cut off fell quickly into the nether worlds wafted by the wind originating from the vital breaths of the Pinaka-bearing lord. *(18-32)*

> On being requested by lord Brahma, the great lord of all the worlds the bestower of everything gave back their own respective bodies to those who were killed. **He gave back the head to Indra, to Visnu,** to Daksa and to the leading sages and others. He gave back the tip of the nose to the goddess Sarasvati and to the mother of Devas. **He gave back life to all those who were destroyed.** *(41-46)*

This incident was known as the destruction of Daksha's sacrifice. **Vishnu actually died for a bit.**